# SQL LEFT JOIN excludes members depending on what it's joined with?

Tags: sql, left-join

I have a database where sometimes language entries are defined for particular item numbers in the "GHS_ItemStoreHandle" table, and sometimes not.  Why does the first query return fewer items than the second query?  Shouldn't both return a number of rows equal to the number of active languages in the "Language" table?

```
SELECT l.NativeName, l.Id, i.ItemNumber, i.StoreHandle FROM Language l 
  LEFT JOIN GHS_ItemStoreHandle i ON l.Code = i.Lang_Code 
  WHERE l.Active = 1 AND 
  (i.ItemNumber = 'MM1-931' OR i.ItemNumber IS NULL) 
  ORDER BY l.NativeName;

SELECT l.NativeName, l.Id, l.Active FROM Language l
  WHERE l.Active = 1
  ORDER BY l.NativeName;
```

Comment: Learn what LEFT JOIN returns: INNER JOIN rows plus unmatched left table rows extended by NULLs. Always know what INNER JOIN you want as part of a LEFT JOIN.

Answer (score 3):

You want the condition in the `ON` clause, not the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT l.NativeName, l.Id, i.ItemNumber, i.StoreHandle
FROM Language l LEFT JOIN
     GHS_ItemStoreHandle i
     ON l.Code = i.Lang_Code AND i.ItemNumber = 'MM1-931'
WHERE l.Active = 1 
ORDER BY l.NativeName;
```

The reason your version returns unexpected results is because sometimes `i` does not have `MM1-931'` but has *another* value.  These are filtered out by your logic.

Comment: This is one of the reasons why I prefer putting all joining conditions in the `JOIN` and filtering conditions in the `WHERE`. It doesn't make a difference in an `INNER JOIN` but it will absolutely change the results in an `OUTER JOIN`.